# Formulario de contacto en PHP + Jquery para habilitar "enviar" funciona pero me llegan correos vacíos [resuelto con Goolge Forms]

Tags: php, formularios, phpmailer, mail

Buenas y ante todo gracias por la ayuda!!
Tengo mi web realizada donde tengo un Formulario de contacto que tiene un botón "enviar" que se activa cuando se completan los campos del formulario (para esto apliqué el javascript:

```html
<!-- Script para validar el Formulario --> 
 <script>
 function validar(frm) {
   frm.sub.disabled = true;
   for (i=0; i<4; i++)
     if (frm['txt'+i].value =='') return
   frm.sub.disabled = false;
 }
 </script>
```

y cuando lo pruebo desde computadoras varias y diferentes celulares funciona perfecto. Pero recibo correos vacíos hace semana y no encuentro realmente el error.
Dejo el código completo de mi formulario:

```html
<section class="contacto py-2 text-center col-md-7">
   <div class="container">
   <h2 class="h3 my-3">CONTACTO</h2>
   <form action="mail/mail.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-9 d-flex align-items-center">
         <p class="hicon"><i class="fas fa-hotel"></i></p>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt0" placeholder="Hotel" onkeyup = "validar(this.form)">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-3 d-flex align-items-center">
         <p class="hicon"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i></p>
         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="txt1" placeholder="Habitaciones" onkeyup = "validar(this.form)">
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
         <p class="hicon"><i class="far fa-user"></i></p>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt2" placeholder="Nombre" onkeyup = "validar(this.form)">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
         <p class="hicon"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></p>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="txt3" placeholder="Email" onkeyup = "validar(this.form)">
       </div>
     </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
         <p class="hicon"><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i></p>
         <input type="web" class="form-control" name="txt4" placeholder="Web">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
         <p class="hicon"><i class="fas fa-align-left"></i></p>
         <input type="texttarea" class="form-control" name="inputMsg" placeholder="Consulta...">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 w-100" name="sub" disabled="disabled" data-placement="top" title="Completar los datos para habilitar el botón" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send">Enviar</button>
       </div>
   </div>
  </form>
   </div>
  </section>
```

y este es el mail.php, que es el básico de phpmailer para enviar un mail con mis datos:

```html
<?php
$Hotel = $_POST["txt0"];  
$Hab = $_POST["txt1"];
$Nombre = $_POST["txt2"]; 
$Email = $_POST["txt3"]; 
$Web = $_POST["txt4"]; 
$Mensaje = $_POST["inputMsg"];

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
//    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted ssl
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->Username   = 'mimail@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'mipass';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to 465

 $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
 );
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('mimail@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('info@hotelop.com');     // Add a recipient
    
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@hotelop.com');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
  //  $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
  //  $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Nuevo Contacto';
    $mail->Body    = 'Nombre: ' . $Nombre . '<br>Hotel: '. $Hotel . '<br>Hab: '. $Hab . '<br>Email: '. $Email . '<br>Web: '. $Web . '<br>Mensaje: '. $Mensaje;
    $mail->AltBody = '';

    $mail->send();
    
    echo 'Enviado';
    header('location:../index.html');
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "MAL. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Gracias de ante mano.
Seba

Comment: ¿Vacío significa **totalmente en blanco** o que te llega `Nombre:`, `Hotel:` etc, sin nada al lado?

Comment: Quita esta línea a ver qué pasa: `$mail->AltBody = '';` puede que te esté cambiando el body por nada debido a esa línea.

Comment: Me llega: Nombre:, Hotel: etc, sin nada al lado...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar poner en `false` esta línea, así **deshabilitas** el *SSL*:

```
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
```

Comment: Cuando lo cambio a false me tira el siguiente error:

Answer (score 0):

Gracias ArtEze pero cuando pongo false me tira el siguiente error:

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: hotelop.oportunidades@gmail.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s66sm4102304otb.65 - gsmtp ,530,5.5.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s66sm4102304otb.65 - gsmtp SMTP code: 530 Additional SMTP info: 5.5.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s66sm4102304otb.65 - gsmtp SMTP code: 530 Additional SMTP info: 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Pueden ser varios problemas:

**1.- Que la variable $_POST este vacia**, para comprobar eso lo mas rapido es hacer un:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Si $_POST esta vacio, prueba con $_post (por probar no sea que te esté instanciando en minusculas en vez de en mayusculas).
Si en cualquier caso tienes una variable vacia es muy probable que tengas un problema en la configuración del servidor PHP porque no esta instanciando la variable $_POST.
En ese caso ejecuta un fichero aparte:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

y comprueba que todo este configurado correctamente

**2.-$_POST tiene datos pero las variables que usas no.**, en este caso lo mas probable es un problema de ambito de variables, o lo que es lo mismo, existen unas variables con valor en el bloque principal pero dentro del bloque de codigo que usas la linea...

```
$mail->Body    = 'Nombre: ' . $Nombre . '<br>Hotel: '. $Hotel . '<br>Hab: '. $Hab . '<br>Email: '. $Email . '<br>Web: '. $Web . '<br>Mensaje: '. $Mensaje;
```

...las variables son null.

Para saber si es este caso, comenta todo lo referente al uso de la libreria de mail y sustituye la line de $mail->Body por un simple:

```
    echo     'Nombre: ' . $Nombre . '<br>Hotel: '. $Hotel . '<br>Hab: '. $Hab . '<br>Email: '. $Email . '<br>Web: '. $Web . '<br>Mensaje: '. $Mensaje;
```

E inserta esa misma linea justo despues de dar valor a las variables.

Si tienen valor al principio pero donde te interesa no, ve moviendo el primer echo abajo hasta que encuentres el punto donde no llegan esas variables.

La solución facil a esto es utilizar dentro del bloque try-catch un:

```
global $Hotel,$Hab,$Nombre,$Email,$Web,$Mensaje;
```

Que no es mi solución favorita pero es muy probable que te funcione

**NOTA AL MARGEN**
Una vez hayas solucionado el problema, Por favor, **filtra las variables para evitar un problema de seguridad**
Por ejemplo:

```
$Email=filter_var($_POST["txt3"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

[Aqui tienes la seccion del manual donde esta el listado de filtros](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Ante todo Oscar, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Pero lo q m sucede es q cuando yo lo pruebo funciona perfecto, es decir me llegan todos los datos que pongo y d hecho el btn enviar no se me habilita si no completo los datos. El tema es q de la nada me llegan mails sin los datos completos. Mi servidor funciona con la versión de PHP 5.5, no sé si eso influye. No puedo solucionarlo y  cuando me llegan esos mails "vacios" no se si son potenciales clientes q no pueden contactarme o si es otra cosa (si entro a google analytics no tengo ingresos en ese horario a mi web, eso me llama la atención).

Comment: Si la versión de php que tienes en remoto es mayor(cosa que es muy probable), influye y mucho...

Comment: Entonces debería solicitar a mi server que aumente (o pagar para que pase) la version de mi PHP? o hay alguna forma de corregirlo?

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar un phpinfo() y mira a ver que version de php tienes y/o que permisos tienes para las variables get y post

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.4. Tengo todo el detalle pero no sé donde ver los permisos de GET y POST, pego en una respuesta todo.

Comment: No me deja pegar toda la descripción. que parte de la configuración busco?

Comment: Tienes que buscar la sección "php variables" y compárala con lo que te sale en local

Comment: Nota: si envias un formulario al fichero que hace el phpinfo() puedes ver lo que está recibiendo en esa misma sección... 

Comment: Es que cuando yo lo pruebo aparece lo que completo, también me lleg correctamente el mail con los datos. pero luego de la nada me cae otro correo sin las datos de la variable, entonces no sé si es que alguien me quiere contactar o es un error o no lo sé. cuando yo lo pruebo, funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Ante todo Oscar, muchas muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda.
Pero lo que me sucede es que cuando yo lo pruebo funciona perfecto, es decir me llegan todos los datos que pongo y de hecho el btn enviar no se me habilita si no completo los datos. El tema es que de la nada me llegan mails sin los datos completos.
Mi servidor funciona con la versión de PHP 5.5, no sé si eso influye.
No puedo solucionarlo y me pone loco cuando me llegan esos mails "vacios" porque no se si son potenciales clientes que no pueden contactarme o si es otra cosa (cuando entro a google analytics no tengo ingresos en ese horario a mi web, eso me llama la atención).
Espero haber sido claro y que me ayudes-

Answer (score 0):

Bueno finalmente lo que hice fue crear un formulario de Gooogle y para que tenga mi CSS lo linkee con la ayuda de esta web: https://www.developerdrive.com/add-google-forms-static-site/

Ahora espero que funcione todo perfecto!